# What locations allow me to speak with my companions?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

Where do I have to go to be able to speak to my companions? My characters do not respond, but I think I'm trying to speak in the wrong locations.

Comment: In your base between the missions. Check the map to see where are they located.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from Haven:

> The best place to get quests and understand your Companions a bit better is to talk to them at Skyhold.

If you don't know where that is, just do the main quests, you'll eventually end up there.

Answer (score 1):

You can speak with your companions and advisors at your home base, for example Haven in the beginning.